# Mocha not executing subsequent FOLDER scripts if the any one of the scripts fails in PREVIOUS folder

Tags: mocha.js, supertest

In my Mocha API Framework for which i am using SUPERTEST I want to to execute all test sequentially in 3 folder. My package.json has a script that executes the test in 3 folder sequentially, however if one scripts FAILS in FOLDER1 then scripts in FOLDER2 is not executed. So basically it is skipping completely all the tests in FOLDER2 and FOLDER3 if any tests fails in FOLDER1 .I am not understanding what should i do

[image: package.json]